# custom android 11 update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I try to develop an android system, I have some problems with development.

I get used to ubuntu18 and tag of **android 11** is **android-11.0.0_r17**,
I have built successfully with lunch 30 **"aosp_x86-eng"** and I have seen `$OUT` files and checked
then I prepared test_aosp.sh file under ~/bin
the results are like that and no emulator window appears:
$ ./test_aosp.sh

```
 emulator: Android emulator version 30.0.21.0 (build_id 6647651) (CL:N/A)
    emulator: Found AVD name 'a25x86'
    emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
    emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: '/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64'
    PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

the content of test_aosp.sh is :

```
 #!/bin/sh
    emulator -avd a25x86 -verbose -show-kernel -system $OUT/system.img -ramdisk $OUT/ramdisk.img -initdata $OUT/userdata.img
```

when I checked ROGER YE notes, before that partition he had run `~/Android/Sdk/emulato/emulator @a25x86`, also I did it with the last version of android studio.

Also, I try to do the following thing but is has a loop in the command line and  the black window of emulator shows up but not appear any menu and any more:

```
  $ sudo ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd a25x86  -verbose -show-kernel -system $OUT/system.img -ramdisk $OUT/ramdisk.img -initdata $OUT/userdata.img
```

also I have checked the emulator location with the following command:

```
  $ which emulator
    /home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator
```

also I want to add following results, maybe you want to check it:

```
 $ printenv |grep ANDROID
ANDROID_DEV_SCRIPTS=/home/ubuntu/aosp/development/scripts:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/tools:/home/ubuntu/aosp/external/selinux/prebuilts/bin:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/dtc:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/libufdt
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_2ND_ARCH=
ANDROID_PRE_BUILD_PATHS=/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/jdk/jdk11/linux-x86/bin:
ANDROID_HOST_OUT_TESTCASES=/home/ubuntu/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/testcases
ANDROID_JAVA_TOOLCHAIN=/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/jdk/jdk11/linux-x86/bin
ANDROID_TARGET_OUT_TESTCASES=/home/ubuntu/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86/testcases
ANDROID_BUILD_TOP=/home/ubuntu/aosp
ANDROID_BUILD_PATHS=/home/ubuntu/aosp/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin:/home/ubuntu/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9/bin:/home/ubuntu/aosp/development/scripts:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/tools:/home/ubuntu/aosp/external/selinux/prebuilts/bin:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/dtc:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/libufdt:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/llvm-binutils-stable:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/asuite/acloud/linux-x86:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/asuite/aidegen/linux-x86:/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/asuite/atest/linux-x86:
ANDROID_EMULATOR_PREBUILTS=/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/home/ubuntu/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86
ANDROID_PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/aosp/development/python-packages:
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9/bin
ANDROID_JAVA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/aosp/prebuilts/jdk/jdk11/linux-x86
ANDROID_HOST_OUT=/home/ubuntu/aosp/out/host/linux-x86
```

Could you guide me?
Thank you
Regards

Comment: I have found something about emulator config.ini file located in ~/.android/avd/a25x86.avd/ file. And this is folder input:
PlayStore.enabled = false
abi.type = x86
avd.ini.encoding = UTF-8
hw.cpu.arch = x86
image.sysdir.1 = system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
tag.display = Google APIs
tag.id = google_apis
disk.dataPartition.size = 6442450944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you successfully built, you can run emulator without additional arguments. Just typing emulator in console.

Or, please try to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT as suggested.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/path/to/your/sdk/for/avd
```

Comment: somebody(?) delete my comments, I could not write any more, could you link the following issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750839/android-11-open-source-project-for-emulator-problem-before-custom-rom