# android 11 open source project for emulator problem before custom rom

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I try to build android open source project, I am at the beginning of it. Initially, I have successfully built android-11.0.0_r17 source code. I have obtained the out files (system.img, ramdisk.img and userdata.img). When I tried to execute following emulator command, it has been failed. I mean, the system has run in a loop and in every cycle the following message has been appeared.

```
$ emulator -avd a25x86 -verbose -show-kernel -system /home/ubuntu/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86/system.img -ramdisk /home/ubuntu/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86/ramdisk.img -initdata /home/ubuntu/aosp/out/target/product/generic_x86/userdata.img

[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.61-android11-0-00791-gbad091cc4bf3-ab6833933 (build-user@build-host) (Android (6443078 based on r383902) clang version 11.0.1 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project b397f81060ce6d701042b782172ed13bee898b79), LLD 11.0.1 (/buildbot/tmp/tmp6_m7QH b397f81060ce6d701042b782172ed13bee898b79)) #1 SMP PREEMPT 2020-09-14 14:42:20
[    0.000000] Command line: qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR30X0X21X0 clocksource=pit console=ttyS0,38400 android.qemud=1 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=260M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.vbmeta.size=6144 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=41e0952e52a1df2eb16607419694ec2a0ecf7eb9cdc3698594df3668cebf05b9 androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 qemu.hwcodec.avcdec=2 qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec=2 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1 mac80211_hwsim.radios=0
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffd5fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ffd6000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feffc000-0x00000000feffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] user-defined physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffd5fff] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000007ffd6000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000feffc000-0x00000000feffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000ff018000-0x00000000ff027fff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.8 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.11.1-0-g0551a4be2c-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
[    0.000000] Hypervisor detected: KVM
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
[    0.000001] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 176bc001, primary cpu clock
[    0.000001] kvm-clock: using sched offset of 10807707590 cycles
[    0.000061] clocksource: kvm-clock: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e4dffb, max_idle_ns: 881590591483 ns
[    0.000190] tsc: Detected 2499.992 MHz processor
[    0.002785] last_pfn = 0x7ffd6 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.003890] x86/PAT: PAT not supported by CPU.
[    0.004039] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WT  UC- UC  WB  WT  UC- UC  
[    0.028057] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f5ae0-0x000f5aef]
[    0.028705] RAMDISK: [mem 0x7fef0000-0x7ffcffff]
[    0.028947] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.029102] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F58E0 000014 (v00 BOCHS )
[    0.029109] ACPI: RSDT 0x000000007FFE1B46 000030 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.029193] ACPI: FACP 0x000000007FFE1A1A 000074 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.029202] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000007FFE0040 0019DA (v01 BOCHS  BXPCDSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.029208] ACPI: FACS 0x000000007FFE0000 000040
[    0.029214] ACPI: APIC 0x000000007FFE1A8E 000080 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.029219] ACPI: HPET 0x000000007FFE1B0E 000038 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCHPET 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.029576] cma: Reserved 260 MiB at 0x000000006f800000
[    0.029632] Zone ranges:
[    0.029634]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.029636]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x000000007ffd5fff]
[    0.029638]   Normal   empty
[    0.029639] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.029640] Early memory node ranges
[    0.029642]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
[    0.029663]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffd5fff]
[    0.029747] Zeroed struct page in unavailable ranges: 140 pages
[    0.029767] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000007ffd5fff]
[    0.043999] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x608
[    0.044090] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
[    0.044518] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.044524] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.044551] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
[    0.044552] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.044595] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
[    0.044597] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
[    0.044606] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.044609] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.044669] smpboot: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.044839] [mem 0x80000000-0xfeffbfff] available for PCI devices
[    0.044841] Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
[    0.044884] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.044912] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:32 nr_cpumask_bits:32 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.045999] percpu: Embedded 53 pages/cpu s176280 r8192 d32616 u1048576
[    0.046158] KVM setup async PF for cpu 0
[    0.046210] kvm-stealtime: cpu 0, msr 7fc17240
[    0.046257] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 515934
[    0.046261] Kernel command line: qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR30X0X21X0 clocksource=pit console=ttyS0,38400 android.qemud=1 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=260M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.vbmeta.size=6144 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=41e0952e52a1df2eb16607419694ec2a0ecf7eb9cdc3698594df3668cebf05b9 androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 qemu.hwcodec.avcdec=2 qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec=2 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1 mac80211_hwsim.radios=0
[    0.047015] Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.047196] Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.047577] mem auto-init: stack:all(zero), heap alloc:on, heap free:off
[    0.053720] Memory: 1758180K/2096592K available (18799K kernel code, 1169K rwdata, 9948K rodata, 1324K init, 1404K bss, 72172K reserved, 266240K cma-reserved)
[    0.053884] random: get_random_u64 called from __kmem_cache_create+0xe8/0x840 with crng_init=0
[    0.054511] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.054633] Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled
[    0.055746] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.055748] rcu:     RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
[    0.055749] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=32 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.055751]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.055752] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.055753] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.058544] NR_IRQS: 4352, nr_irqs: 440, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.059243] rcu:     Offload RCU callbacks from CPUs: (none).
[    0.597708] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.600758] ACPI: Core revision 20190816
[    0.604794] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604467 ns
[    0.613056] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.629022] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.633744] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x24093255d7c, max_idle_ns: 440795319144 ns
[    0.641622] Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 4999.98 BogoMIPS (lpj=9999968)
[    0.645609] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.649716] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.653643] SELinux:  Initializing.
[    0.657628] Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.661585] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.670286] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
[    0.673577] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
[    0.677584] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    0.681582] Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Full generic retpoline
[    0.685576] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
[    0.689577] Speculative Store Bypass: Vulnerable
[    0.693584] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    0.700260] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 56K
[    0.814510] smpboot: CPU0: Intel Android virtual processor (family: 0x6, model: 0x6, stepping: 0x3)
[    0.817989] Performance Events: generic architected perfmon v1, core PMU driver.
[    0.821584] core: CPUID marked event: 'cpu cycles' unavailable
[    0.825577] core: CPUID marked event: 'instructions' unavailable
[    0.829577] core: CPUID marked event: 'bus cycles' unavailable
[    0.833577] core: CPUID marked event: 'cache references' unavailable
[    0.837577] core: CPUID marked event: 'cache misses' unavailable
[    0.841577] core: CPUID marked event: 'branch instructions' unavailable
[    0.845577] core: CPUID marked event: 'branch misses' unavailable
.....
[    2.739616] xt_time: kernel timezone is -0000
[    2.743417] ipip: IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.748025] gre: GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
[    2.752417] ip_gre: GRE over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.757220] IPv4 over IPsec tunneling driver
[    2.762571] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.765857] IPsec XFRM device driver
[    2.768642] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.772915] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.776067] mip6: Mobile IPv6
[    2.779628] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.785399] ip6_gre: GRE over IPv6 tunneling driver
[    2.789394] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.793124] NET: Registered protocol family 15
[    2.797482] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.802094] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.808480] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    2.811833] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[    2.816092] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[    2.819892] l2tp_core: L2TP core driver, V2.0
[    2.823153] l2tp_ppp: PPPoL2TP kernel driver, V2.0
[    2.826713] tipc: Activated (version 2.0.0)
[    2.829935] NET: Registered protocol family 30
[    2.833236] tipc: Started in single node mode
[    2.837348] IPI shorthand broadcast: enabled
[    2.840593] SSE version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    2.851004] sched_clock: Marking stable (2280747994, 570242742)->(3133591105, -282600369)
[    2.857699] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.860708] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.864144] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    2.867152] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    2.870597] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    2.874560] pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
[    2.879245] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    2.886723] cryptomgr_probe (100) used greatest stack depth: 14248 bytes left
[    2.887065] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    2.901940] ALSA device list:
[    2.905505] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    2.909830]   No soundcards found.
[    2.914951] platform regulatory.0: Falling back to sysfs fallback for: regulatory.db
[    2.931774] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1324K
[    2.978211] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 30720k
[    2.995144] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1680K
[    3.003620] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 292K
[    3.012187] Run /init as init process
[    3.029628] init: init first stage started!
[    3.036823] init: Unable to open /lib/modules, skipping module loading.
[    3.047992] init: [libfs_mgr]ReadFstabFromDt(): failed to read fstab from dt
[    3.059464] init: [libfs_mgr]ReadDefaultFstab(): failed to find device default fstab
[    3.072069] init: Failed to fstab for first stage mount
[    3.080806] init: Using Android DT directory /proc/device-tree/firmware/android/
[    3.093390] init: First stage mount skipped (missing/incompatible/empty fstab in device tree)
[    3.106700] init: Skipped setting INIT_AVB_VERSION (not in recovery mode)
[    3.118439] init: execv("/system/bin/init") failed: No such file or directory
[    3.125095] init: InitFatalReboot: signal 6
[    3.139460] Unregister pv shared memory for cpu 0
[    3.142974] Unregister pv shared memory for cpu 1
[    3.146555] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    3.153437] reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootloader'
[    3.159962] reboot: machine restart
emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default
```

I think it is about "Unable to open /lib/modules, skipping module loading". When I checked the ramdisk.img with gzip and I saw "init" file. Could you guide me at that point? Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.
Best regards.

Comment: any recommendation?

Comment: Hi ...I am also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are following the `Android System Programming` book and are unable to do what the book says. I've been there.

**Note:** If you aren't building the AOSP in the headless workstation and running the emulator in your desktop PC, you can just type `emulator` after you finished building image. The android build system already setup everything you needed. But if it's not the case, continue reading.

To fix the issue, do the following steps. (The procedure is depending on the operating system you're using, so I can't provide you with a copy-and-paste solution).

1. Set `$ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT` environment variable to point to any valid file path to fool the Android Emulator program that you are using it in an android build system. The android emulator program detects whether it is being used in android build system by checking the existence of the `$ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT`
2. Pass `-sysdir` command line argument to the `emulator` that points to `$AOSP_ROOT\out\target\product\generic_x86\`. The Android emulator uses the `-sysdir` argument to look for `system.img`, `vendor.img`, `ramdisk.img`,  `userdata.img` and `kernel-qemu`. you can take a look at `emulator -help-build-images` for more information.
3. If you're using a modern Android version for your setup, it is very likely that the kernel being used is `kernel-ranchu`. So let the Android emulator know where to find your kernel image by providing `-kernel` command line argument `-kernel $AOSP_ROOT\out\target\product\generic_x86\kernel-ranchu-64`.
4. For some reasons, my Android emulator setup can't find `userdata.img`, so I have to also provide that as a command line argument as well `-data $AOSP_ROOT\out\target\product\generic_x86\userdata.img`.

This is a command that works for my setup on Windows.

`cmd /V /C "set ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=J:\aosp\mainline\out\target\product\generic_x86\&& emulator -sysdir J:\aosp\mainline\out\target\product\generic_x86\ -kernel J:\aosp\mainline\out\target\product\generic_x86\kernel-ranchu-64 -data J:\aosp\mainline\out\target\product\generic_x86\userdata.img -show-kernel -no-snapshot"`